# Best python library to use for a BNF based autocompleter

Tags: python, parsing

I want to create a SQL autocompleter for use with rlwrap: https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap
This could then be used with sqlite3 & osqueri for example (I know they already have some autocompletion facility, but it's not good enough, especially under rlwrap).
In fact, more generally I would like to know the best approach for building autocompleters based on BNF grammar descriptions; I may want to produce autocompleters for other rlwrapped REPLs at some point in the future.
I have no experience with parsers, but I have read some stuff online about the different types of parsers and how they work, and this Pyleri tutorial: https://tomassetti.me/pyleri-tutorial/ 
Pyleri looks fairly straightforward, and has the `expecting` property which makes it easy to create a auto-completer, but AFAIK it would involve translating the sqlite BNF (and any other BNF's that I might want to use in the future) into python code, which is a drag.
ANTLR has lots of predefined grammar files for many different languages, and the ability to output python code, but I'm not sure how easy it is to produce an autocompleter, and I don't want to read through all the documentation only to find out I've wasted my time.
So can anyone advise me? What's the best approach?

Comment: Antlr4 has a python target. In addition, Mike has a "code completion" library [here](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3). I've written my own for C#, too. There is no port to Python, but one could write one given the source to the other three targets in his code. Antlr4 isn't BNF. BNF doesn't have Kleene closure operators and grouping. Antlr uses EBNF, which Antlr4 takes advantage of with smaller CST's.